# ngx datatable does it have a column reorder event Angular

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I am using ngx data table to show info to users , by default you can drag the columns and rearrange them but then after that it gets lost if you navigate to a new page and come back .

I want to be able to persist the column rearrangement either to the store so some api call . Is there any event we have once we rearrange the columns so that i can look at the rearranged data and do all these . I looked at their documentation but could find none .

https://swimlane.gitbooks.io/ngx-datatable/introduction/features.html

Comment: Were you able to persist the order update? If so, how did you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does have a Column reorder event . 
This [**`LINK`**](https://swimlane.gitbooks.io/ngx-datatable/api/table/outputs.html#reorder) will help you .

It is called **reorder** emitter.

```
(reorder) = 'reordered($event)'>
```

Comment: Could you please explain it with example if u have